# Html, css horizontal and vertical splitter

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a splitter which is similar to [this](https://bertrandg.github.io/angular-split/old_0.2.x/#/examples).
but I want it to work horizontally and vertically at the same time. [Here](https://ibb.co/cHt5WU) is a picture about the concept. So it is kinda like how [jsfiddle](https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/examples/jsfiddle.html) works, but I want to control the vertical lines separately too.

I just need the idea how to solve it with html and css. I will solve the splitter's movement with javascript.

Thx

Comment: I don't think the geometry would work out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is with the usage of the on-resize event and calculate the width and height of the elements dynamically based on a fixed limit. I made a little prove of concept, using jQuery and jQueryUI(for the resizing). The core of the concept is:

```
$("#a").resizable({
    //listen to the event of resize
    resize: function() {
        //calculate and set the new widths and heights of the elements
        $("#b").width(500 - $(this).width());
        ...
    }
});
```

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/cxfghe0a/25/

Here are the reference for the elements used:

- https://api.jquery.com/resize/
- https://api.jquery.com/width/
- http://jqueryui.com/resizable/